# STL + typedefs vs. OOP, best practices?

Tags: c++, oop, stl, typedef

I "grew up" learning to set up data structures using OOP. But now as I learn more about C++, STL, and Boost, I find that many of my data structure needs can be met by combining STL classes into more complex composites like:

```
typedef std::map<std::string, std::map<std::string, int> > CSVData;
```

Obviously there are limits to this when I need to mix data types, but generally I find myself avoiding OOP when I can in favor of these STL composites for their simplicity. Is this a common progression? Are there best-practice rules-of-thumb for when it's better to define your own class? Are there common pitfalls to this?

Comment: You could check this: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/70201/should-i-be-coding-this-myself"

Comment: Why all the close votes? This is **not subjective** (and almost all problems are at least somewhat argumentative)! There are good *technical* reasons to prefer one over the other. **Don’t close this question**, it’s completely legitimate and on topic!

Comment: @Konrad We can (and will) always re-open it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If this is for some one-off code: sure, use typedefs, why not?

But code rarely is. And the problem with reusable code (or code that will, potentially, at some future point be reused) is: there are 1000 different ways of using it wrongly. Don’t artificially add reasons 1001–1255.

**Code should be easy to use, and hard to misuse.** Among other things this means: have *one* obvious interface and forbid all operations that aren’t supported, meaningful, or that are somehow unnecessary. Providing a typedef fails in this regard: your CSV data type supports all kinds of irrelevant operations.

There are multiple other reasons against typedefs: for instance, this makes the interface easy to break when you need to change the underlying implementation of your data structure (change of requirements, performance issues …). Essentially, you cannot do that without breaking all uses of your typedef’d data structure.

But a properly designed, well encapsulated data structure can easily change its internal implementation without breaking consumer code, as long as the interface remains identical.

This is one of the most important concepts of large architectures: *information hiding*.

Furthermore, it is a logical error (albeit a small one): your typedef models a logical is-a relation. But this isn’t true: CSV data isn’t a map of maps. Rather, it can be *implemented in terms of* a map of maps. This is a fundamental difference.

That said, C++ *does* teach that object orientation isn’t needed for large object hierarchies: essentially the whole standard library (except for the IO stream library) *isn’t* object oriented: it’s *algorithm oriented* instead. But that doesn’t mean that you don’t have to write your own classes.

Comment: +1: Some very strong arguments here.

Comment: good arguments, quite a bit of my code does end up being one-offs though, so the balance between clean encapsulation and time-to-development may be skewed for me.

Comment: @Darryl I used to be strongly opposed to one-off code because *you cannot know* which code you end up reusing and sloppy, supposedly “one-off” code can come back to bite you. But with a bit of care you can still limit the harm that such code can do.

Answer (score 4):

I think most of us write less and less OO code as we get older. The urge to turn everything into an object and construct Byzantine inheritance hierarchies tends to fade in the experience of maintaining these things.

Answer (score 0):

Surely a sensible rule of thumb is to find a happy medium between:

- **Don't reinvent the wheel.** (If they serve your purpose, use existing constructs.)
- **Make sure your code is readable and maintainable.** (There comes a point where the reader will find it very difficult to keep track of all the nested templating, etc., even with judicious use of typedefs.)

Answer (score 0):

I tend to avoid pure typedef **outside** a class (apart from the typical alias to save some typing in a file/function).

There are two (closely related) reasons, and both stems from the same fact: I can control what operations/methods are available on my class:

- I can give them proper names, pertaining to the problem domain, instead of generic names
- I can control the implementations of those methods: maintaining invariants, adding debugging informations / assertions

Of course, I would then use the typedef within the class, and delegate the bulk of the implementation to those already coding methods, but do not sneer at the thin layer on top of it. It's valuable.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's in *Effective C++* (Third Edition) that Scott Meyer's emphasizes that C++ supports several different programming paradigms.  Object-orientation is one of them.  Generic programming (STL-style) is another.  There are others as well.

There's nothing wrong with using the style that's most appropriate to the problem you're trying to solve.  And in a larger project, there may indeed be some parts you want to solve with generics and some you want to solve with object orientation.  You want to be aware of whichever mode you're in, but I don't see a problem taking advantage of both.

It's natural, as you're learning something new, to use it more and more.  When your experience with generics catches up with your OO experience, you might notice a more balanced approach in your intuition.

Answer (score 0):

It is always best to program against an *interface*, rather than a concrete implementation.

As @adrian-mccarthy mentioned, C++ is a multi-paradigm language, and there are several different ways to program against an interface.

One way is to use OOP.

Another way, is to write templates.

Instead of using the `typedef` directly, templatize your client code to work with any container implementing the same concepts. (The Boost Static Assertions and Boost Concept Checking facilities may be helpful in locking down precisely which concepts your algorithm depends on.)

The decision to templatize is, of course, implies certain non-trivial changes to your code organization (moving method implementations into headers).  It is up to you to decide if it is appropriate.

Comment: thanks, being more familiar with the OO paradigm, I'm still getting my head wrapped around template programming. Part of me is a little wary of investing a lot of effort into a paradigm that is strongly tied to a single language (the principles are general, but few other major languages seem to support it), but that's probably a different conversation.